# Reducing number of repeated queries in Django when creating new objects in a loop

Tags: python, django, performance

I'm populating a database using Django from an Excel sheet. In the example below, the `purchases` list simulates the format of that sheet.

My problem is that I'm repeatedly using `Customer.objects.get` to retrieve the same `Customer` object when creating new `Purchase` entries. This results in repeated database queries for the same information.

I've tried using `customers = Customer.objects.all()` to read in the whole `Customer` table into memory, but that doesn't seem to have worked since `customers.get()` still creates a new database query each time.

```py
from django.db import models

# My classes
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=50, unique=True)

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=50, unique=True)

class Purchase(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey("Customer", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item = models.ForeignKey("Customer", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

# My data
purchase_table =[
    {'customer': 'Joe', 'item': 'Toaster'},
    {'customer': 'Joe', 'item': 'Slippers'},
    {'customer': 'Jane', 'item': 'Microwave'}
]

# Populating DB
for purchase in purchase_table:
    
    # Get item and customer (this is where the inefficient use of 'get' takes place)
    item = Item.objects.get(name=purchase['item'])
    customer = Customer.objects.get(name=purchase['customer'])
    
    # Create new purchase
    Purchase(customer, item).save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're dealing with small enough data to read into memory, then why not use `.all()` like you mentioned? That should do the trick.

Something like:

```
items = {item.name: item for item in Item.objects.all()}
customers = {customer.name: customer for customer in Customer.objects.all()}

purchases = [Purchase(customers[c], items[i]) for c, i in zip(items, customers)]
Purchase.objects.bulk_create(purchases)
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. One small thing, in the first two lines, I think it needs to be `{item.name : item...}` and `{customer.name: customer ...}`

Answer (score 1):

There could be a better way, but i would have done this way to minimize database transactions.

```
from django.db import transaction

# My data
purchase_table =[
    {'customer': 'Joe', 'item': 'Toaster'},
    {'customer': 'Joe', 'item': 'Slippers'},
    {'customer': 'Jane', 'item': 'Microwave'}
]

# I am assuming name field is unique in Item as well as Customer
customers = {customer['name']: customer['id'] for customer in Customer.objects.values()}

items = {item['name']: item['id'] for item in Items.objects.values()}

with transaction.atomic():    
    for purchase in purchase_table:
        customer = customers.get(purchase['customer'])
        item = items.get(purchase['item'])
        if item and customer:
            Purchase(customer_id=customer, item_id=item).save()
```

Refer [transaction.atomic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic) for more details.